# Connecting to Corda Enterprise node with Corda OS RPC client

Tags: corda

I'm playing with Corda Enterprise for the first time. It appears that one cannot connect to an enterprise-node with the `net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient` from the `net.corda:corda-rpc:3.1-corda` (or `corda-3.0`) artifacts in maven central. The following error is thrown:

> [WARN ] 2018-07-11T14:01:50,969Z [Thread-10
>   (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)]
>   internal.SerializationFactoryImpl.apply - Cannot find serialization
>   scheme for: [([636F7264610000], RPCServer), UNKNOWN MAGIC]
>   registeredSchemes are:
>   [net.corda.node.serialization.amqp.AMQPServerSerializationScheme@2d76d0f2,
>   net.corda.client.rpc.internal.serialization.amqp.AMQPClientSerializationScheme@423613e1,
>   net.corda.node.serialization.kryo.KryoServerSerializationScheme@5426cf17]
>   {}
>
> [WARN ] 2018-07-11T14:01:50,970Z [Thread-10
>   (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)]
>   messaging.RPCServer.clientArtemisMessageHandler - Inbound RPC failed
>   {actor_id=user, actor_owningIdentity=O=Localhost, L=Zurich, C=CH,
>   actor_store_id=NODE_CONFIG,
>   invocation_id=170d59d3-5c5c-4061-ad6f-cfe314cd58dd,
>   invocation_timestamp=2018-07-11T14:01:50.970Z,
>   session_id=4e194037-fdce-4849-a6c5-ae453d3bd314,
>   session_timestamp=2018-07-11T14:01:48.801Z}
>
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Serialization scheme
>   ([636F7264610000], RPCServer) not supported.
>
> at net.corda.serialization.internal.SerializationFactoryImpl$schemeFor$1.apply(SerializationScheme.kt:130)
>   ~[corda-serialization-3.0.jar:?]

I can connect though if I use the `com.r3.corda:corda-rpc:3.0` artifact that's provided in the Corda Enterprise `DeveloperPack`.

Is there a chance that future releases of the Corda open-source client will be able to talk to a Corda Enterprise node ? It would be more convenient for us since we would not have to create different distributions of our software.

Answer (score 1):

This will be possible from Corda 4 onwards.